# Fluig - Mysql 8 Connector

Tags: java, conexão, mysql

Não consigo fazer subir meu servidor Fluig, porque dá o erro

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Public Key Retrieval is not allowed
```

Pesquisando exaustivamente, [descobri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50379839/connnection-java-mysql-public-key-retrieval-is-not-allowed/50438872) que eu precisaria alterar o valor da propriedade

```
allowPublicKeyRetrieval
```

para true.

Fui ao MySql Workbench 8 para ver, mas não encontrei a propriedade através Local Instance, Options File.

O caminho era este msmo? Onde posso fazer essa verificação?

Comment: No link que você postou, acredito que é para você adicionar esse parâmetro na URL de conexão algo como: `jdbc:mysql://address:port/database?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false`

Comment: Caro @ViktorHugo, o problema é justamente este. Onde fazer isto?

Answer (score -1):

Para mais informações: [Documentação Fluig Datasources](http://tdn.totvs.com/pages/releaseview.action?pageId=243654987)

A configuração é bem simples, o fluig usa jboss como servidor de aplicação. Precisamos alterar o arquivo **standalone.xml** onde fica as configurações de datasources.

> (Fique atento de acordo com sua versão do Fluig)

- Caso utilize a versão 1.5.13 ou inferior edite o arquivo
  standalone.xml localizado em [Instalação
  fluig]\jboss\standalone\configuration.
- Caso utilize a versão 1.6 ou superior,  edite o arquivo domain.xml
  localizado em [Instalação fluig]\appserver\domain\configuration.

Você vai localizar a tag **datasources** que representa a conexão com MySQL e  alterar a configuração da tag **connection-url**, segue um exemplo:

```
<datasources>

   <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS" pool-name="MySqlDS">

      <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://address:port/database?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false</connection-url>

     ...

      <security>

        <user-name>seu usuario</user-name>

        <password>sua senha</password>

      </security>

     ...

    </datasource>

  ...

</datasources>
```